# Memcached not storing value above 100 Bytes properly

Tags: php, memcached

I am trying to use memcached for caching users data. But for some reason the value (users data) turns into strange characters whenever the size of value become more that or equal to 100 Bytes.

```
$m = new Memcached;
$m->addServer('127.0.0.1', 11211);

$m->set('key', array('abc' => 'xyz', 'password' => 'gautam', 'abc1' => 'xyz', 'password1' => 'g')); 
// The above works fine
// a:4:{s:3:"abc";s:3:"xyz";s:8:"password"; s:6:"gautam";s:4:"abc1";s:3:"xyz";s:9:"p assword1";s:1:"g";}

$m->set('key', array('abc' => 'xyz', 'password' => 'gautam', 'abc1' => 'xyz', 'password1' => 'g')); 
// Data becomes corrupt
// xœK´2±ª.¶2¶RJLJV²³**«@, 
+¥‚Äââòü¢×ÌJ) =±´$1Ä1«7DÕ`‰Ð
```

Can someone please help me fix this problem. I think memcached value can be upto 1M.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check config, try this link to get the config options of memcached:

http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewConfiguringServer

Answer (score 1):

At least with the PHP Memcached module, they do some sort of compression for values over 100 bytes.  My Python client wasn't expecting that and would go crazy whenever I hit a 100+ letter string.  This fixed it for me:

```
$m->setOption(Memcached::OPT_COMPRESSION, false);
```